# Disable all buttons on click of any of the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 `Buttons` in an aspx page. One for `Save as Draft`, 2nd for `Cancel` and 3rd for `submit`.
Now I want that whenever I click on any of the 3 `Buttons` then all the 3 `Buttons` should get disabled.

Comment: you can do it using jquery like this $("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", true);

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
private void ButtonDisable(Control ct)
{
    foreach(Control c in ct.Controls)
    {
        if (c is Button)
        {
           c.Enabled = false;;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with jQuery

```
$(":submit").click( function () {
   $(":submit").each( function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   });
});
```

It will disable your buttons before starting execution of any server side code

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using JavaScript (without jQuery). The following code uses `document.querySelectorAll` which would work in all modern browsers.

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button');


[].forEach.call(button, function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        disableAllButtons();
        return false;
    });
});

function disableAllButtons(){
    [].forEach.call(button, function (btn) {
        btn.disabled=true;
    });
}
```

The [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/m7gejfdn/).

Comment: Its not working fine with me. None of the buttons getting disabled

Comment: Can you share your aspx code. Also on which browser did you test

Answer (score 0):

Here is small and sweet answer.

Give common cssclass to all buttons and then use following code for OnClientClick="funDisableButtons()" event.

```
function funDisableButtons()
{
    $(".className").attr("disabled", true);
}
```